# Как вывести вопросы именно той темы,которые выбрал пользователь?

Tags: android

Здравствуйте.Я хотел бы сделать quiz game. Она содержит около 50 тем.Все вопросы я храню в БД.  После запуска приложение,пользователь выбирает тему и отвечает на вопрос с 4 ответами.Вывести на экран все вопросы,я могу. Но проблема в том,как вывести именно вопросы той темы,которые выбрал пользователь? Я думал создать, Database классы для каждой темы. Но тем слишком много. Надеюсь, я вам смог донести проблему.

Comment: сделайте просто выборку из БД по теме. В чем проблема?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM questions WHERE theme = 'тут нужная тема'`

Comment: Одна таблица с вопросами должна быть - questions. В `questions` есть поле theme_id. Отдельно таблица themes с темами. Для каждой темы не нужен отдельный класс или таблица. Выбирайте вопросы sql-запросом с условием where theme_id=?d...

Answer (score 2):

Создайте БД с колонками _id (обязательная колонка),тема,вопрос,ответ. Заполните ее. И далее  формированием соответствующего запроса к БД, например в cursor, прописываете необходимые условия выборки для заполнения соответствующих view. В вашем случае cursor  должен заполняться программно. Пользователь выбирает тему и этот выбор идет параметром в cursor. Также можно построить БД с использованием нескольких таблиц, тогда придется вводить какие либо идентификаторы связывающие вопросы с темами и в cursor уже передавать их.